# How the regular expression search in opposite direction in python

Tags: python, regex

For example. The string is following
`"cd 1.2  ab  2.3 cd"` .
If I use pattern  `"[0-9]*\.[0-9]*"`, and `re.search` to find the sub-string.  It will return `1.2`. I want to return `2.3`.
How can I have the python search in opposite direction. I don't like to use `findall` function to get all of the sub-strings. then use the last one

Comment: Why doesn't `re.findall(r'regex', string)[-1]` work for you?

Comment: If use `findall`, I think it can't get the best performance

Comment: I just tested both. `findall()` with your regex is actually about 7% faster than `.search()` with @Lindrian's regex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would work in this case: `\d+\.\d+(?=\D*$)`

It will grab the last digits when there are no others following it in the entire string.

Demo+explanation: http://regex101.com/r/hE0lE4

Answer (score 0):

using `re.finditer()`:

```
In [150]: strs="cd 1.2 ab 2.3 cd"

In [151]: for x in re.finditer(r"\d+\.\d+",strs):pass

In [152]: x.group()
Out[152]: '2.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last one (or last ones where you are willing to match a pattern) just use the greediest `.*` match up to the last pattern match of interest:

```
>>> import re
>>> st="cd 1.2 dv 1.4 ab 2.3 cd"
>>> re.match(r'.*(\d\.\d)',st).group(1)
'2.3'
```

But `re.findall` is more flexible and straightforward and probably the fastest:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\d\.\d)',st)
['1.2', '1.4', '2.3']
>>> re.findall(r'(\d\.\d)',st)[-1]
'2.3'
>>> re.findall(r'(\d\.\d)',st)[-2]
'1.4'
```

Of course, you can reverse the string, match the FIRST match with a reversed regex (if it is not symmetrical), and reverse the result back:

```
>>> re.search(r'(\d\.\d)',st[::-1]).group(1)[::-1]
'2.3'
```

[Which is done regularly in Perl](http://www.perl.com/pub/2001/05/01/expressions.html)

Comment: what does it mean when usr `()` with other string in the pattern.

Comment: @Samuel: The `()` form a capturing group. Not strictly needed with `findall` but it is needed with `re.match` and `re.search` to form a pattern to capture.

Comment: `(?=)` and `(?<=)` mean the after and before of the string. I just know this. Is `()` a ABBR of `(?=)` or `(?<=)`

Comment: @Samuel: Those are negative and positive look aheads. The `?` inside the parens makes it into something different than a match group. Let's say you have `re.search(r'(\d)\d(\d)','1234')` The first match group will be `'1'` and the second match group will be `'3'`    Try it:`re.search(r'(\d)\d(\d)','1234').group(1)` and then change the `1` to `2` inside the last parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

```
   1. re.search('[0-9]*\.[0-9]*',a[::-1]).group()


   2. re.search(r'(\d\.\d)(\s\w+$)',a).group(1)
```